# Portable way to resolve host name to IP address

Tags: shell, dns, sh

I need to resolve a host name to an IP address in a shell script. The code must work at least in `Cygwin`, `Ubuntu` and `OpenWrt`(`busybox`). 
It can be assumed that each host will have only one IP address.

Example:

- input

  ```
  google.com
  ```
- output

  ```
  216.58.209.46
  ```

**EDIT:**
`nslookup` may seem like a good solution, but its output is quite unpredictable and difficult to filter. Here is the result command on my computer (`Cygwin`):

```
>nslookup google.com
Unauthorized answer:
Serwer:  UnKnown
Address:  fdc9:d7b9:6c62::1

Name:   google.com
Addresses:  2a00:1450:401b:800::200e
          216.58.209.78
```

Comment: If you need your code to work in `busybox`, then it's not bash; that means you need POSIX sh compatibility, which is a different language (though bash is a superset, just as C++ is a superset of C). Please tag appropriately.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thank you! I did not know the difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want something available out-of-the-box on almost any modern UNIX, use Python:

```
pylookup() {
  python -c 'import socket, sys; print socket.gethostbyname(sys.argv[1])' "$@" 2>/dev/null
}

address=$(pylookup google.com)
```

---

With respect to special-purpose tools, `dig` is far easier to work with than `nslookup`, and its `short` mode emits only literal answers -- in this case, IP addresses. To take only the first address, if more than one is found:

```
# this is a bash-specific idiom
read -r address < <(dig +short google.com | grep -E '^[0-9.]+$')
```

If you need to work with POSIX sh, or broken versions of bash (such as Git Bash, built with mingw, where process substitution doesn't work), then you might instead use:

```
address=$(dig +short google.com | grep -E '^[0-9.]+$' | head -n 1)
```

---

`dig` is available for cygwin in the `bind-utils` package; as `bind` is most widely used DNS server on UNIX, `bind-utils` (built from the same codebase) is available for almost all Unix-family operating systems as well.

Comment: I wish command was available by default. It is not a problem for me, but other users of the script may complain. However, this is very simple, so I like this.

Comment: @NO_NAME, what *do* you consider "available by default"? Does Python work, if I provided a one-liner that used it?

Comment: This question is a lot trickier than I first thought. This answer works perfectly when the hostname is an A record. However, if the hostname is a CNAME, then the first line printed by `dig +short` is the canonical name.

Comment: "available by default" - I mean, you don't need to install any package which is not selected by default.

Comment: Yes, but what is or isn't out-of-the-box is different for every OS and distro, which is why I need to ask: For the platforms you care about, is Python available by default?

Comment: @AnthonyGeoghegan, good catch, thanks. Adjusted (albeit with an ugly hack) appropriately.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Nice work. That's now an excellent answer and I've no choice but to upvote it. Plus one for the Python solution.

Comment: I tried version with `dig` on all three shells and it is works exactly the same. Great!

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 comes with python3 by default. I'm not sure if there's a python version-agnostic way of doing this, but the python3 way is like this:
pylookup() {
  python3 -c 'import socket, sys; print(socket.gethostbyname(sys.argv[1]))' "$@" 2>/dev/null
}

Comment: @RossTajvar, is the only thing you had to change the parens around the arguments to `print`? If so, Python 2 should tolerate that. If you need to support platforms where no `python` command exists, I suppose you could do something like `pylookup() { if command -v python3 >/dev/null 2>&1; then python3 -c '...'; else python -c '...'; fi; }`

Comment: @CharlesDuffy there was no "python" on my system because it only had python3, so I did have to change the command as well. I tried your version and it seems like it doesn't pick up the argument passed to the bash function. print(sys.argv) returns ['-c'].

Comment: Perhaps I should have written `python -c ...`, to make it more clear I was eliding the rest of each line. You still need the `"$@"` syntax from the answer.

Answer (score 7):

I've no experience with OpenWRT or Busybox but the following one-liner will should work with a base installation of Cygwin or Ubuntu:

```
ipaddress=$(LC_ALL=C nslookup $host 2>/dev/null  | sed -nr '/Name/,+1s|Address(es)?: *||p')
```

The above works with both the Ubuntu and Windows version of nslookup. However, it only works when the DNS server replies with **one** IP (v4 or v6) address; if more than one address is returned the first one will be used.

---

#### Explanation

`LC_ALL=C nslookup` sets the `LC_ALL` environment variable when running the `nslookup` command so that the command ignores the current system locale and print its output in the command’s default language (English).

The `2>/dev/null` avoids having warnings from the Windows version of `nslookup` about non-authoritative servers being printed.

The sed command looks for the line containing `Name` and then prints the following line after stripping the phrase `Addresses:` when there's more than one IP (v4 or 6) address -- or `Address:` when only one address is returned by the name server.

The `-n` option means lines aren't printed unless there's a `p` command`while the`-r` option means extended regular expressions are used (GNU sed is the default for Cygwin and Ubuntu).

Comment: I tried this in Cygwin. There are a few problems. I'll update mu question with them.

Comment: The problem is that in different language versions, the messages are different. You can not assume that somewhere will be written `Name`. Anyway, thank you for your answer.

Comment: To be honest, I have polish version of `Windows`. There is `Nazwa` and not `Name`. There is more changes, like this.

Comment: I updated my `Cygwin` and it use unix version of `nslooup` now.

Comment: @NO_NAME Doh! I didn't consider that! You could modify the sed extended regex to `/Name|Nazwa/` to work in other locales. You're question gets harder all the time. :)

Comment: Easier to just set `LC_ALL=C` for the scope of your command (ie. `LC_ALL=C nslookup`), and thereby ignore current system locale sections.

Comment: Good thinking, @CharlesDuffy  I've edited my answer to include your suggestion. Thanks. BTW, since originally answering this question, I've moved towards preferring `dig` (as per your answer) over `nslookup`.

Comment: Sometimes nslookup returns Name: askedHostName\nAddress 1: ipAddress1 nameOfHost\n... so Address N, and a hostname after the IP. So your pattern fails. (Ah, same output as in answer from Octetta.) Output of nslookup really seems to be very varrying. Tried with `busybox nslookup debian.org` , version: BusyBox v1.22.1 But version BusyBox v1.31.1 does not do both of this anymore ...

Answer (score 3):

> **TL;DR;** Option 2 is my preferred choice for IPv4 address. Adjust the regex to get IPv6 and/or `awk` to get both. There is a slight edit to option 2 suggested use given in **EDIT**

Well a terribly late answer here, but I think I'll share my solution here, esp. because the accepted answer didn't work for me on openWRT(no python with minimal setup) and the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31303256/1369473) errors out "no address found after comma".

**Option 1 (gives the last address from last entry sent by nameserver):**

```
nslookup example.com 2>/dev/null | tail -2 | tail -1 | awk '{print $3}'
```

Pretty simple and straight forward and doesn't really need an explanation of piped commands.

Although, in my tests this always gave IPv4 address (because IPv4 was always last line, at least in my tests.) However, I read about the unexpected behavior of `nslookup`. So, I had to find a way to make sure I get IPv4 even if the order was reversed - thanks `regex`

**Option 2 (makes sure you get IPv4):**

```
nslookup example.com 2>/dev/null | sed 's/[^0-9. ]//g' | tail -n 1 | awk -F " " '{print $2}'
```

Explanation:

`nslookup example.com 2>/dev/null` - look up given host and ignore STDERR (`2>/dev/null`)

`sed 's/[^0-9. ]//g'` - regex to get IPv4 (numbers and dots, read about 's' command [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/The-_0022s_0022-Command.html))

`tail -n 1` - get last 1 line (alt, `tail -1`)

`awk -F " " '{print $2}` - Captures and prints the second part of line using " " as a field separator

**EDIT:** A slight modification based on a comment to make it actually more generalized:

```
nslookup example.com 2>/dev/null | printf "%s" "$(sed 's/[^0-9. ]//g')" | tail -n 1 | printf "%s" "$(awk -F " " '{print $1}')"
```

In the above edit, I'm using `printf` command substitution to take care of any unwanted trailing newlines.

Comment: Your answer bases on a bunch of assumptions that are true only on OpenWRT. This is not portable at all. Check out output of `nslookup` command which I pasted in question.

Answer (score 3):

Here's my variation that steals from earlier answers:

`nslookup blueboard 2> /dev/null | awk '/Address/{a=$3}END{print a}'`

This depends on nslookup returning matching lines that look like:

`Address 1: 192.168.1.100 blueboard`

...and only returns the last address.

Caveats: this doesn't handle non-matching hostnames at all.

Comment: The matching does not work when the output is `Address: 192...` or `Addresses: ...` (as in the question).

Comment: Can be improved to handle nonmaching hostnames: `awk '/Name/ {inName=1} inName&&/Address/ {print $3; exit}'` (This prints the first match only.)